# Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ notifications are off-kilter in new design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Look in the top left of the below image, you'll notice that the 1 message is not quite on top of the Stack Exchange speech bubble. Looks to just be a miss on positioning.

[image]

Comment: noted. thanks! fix is on the way.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Stack+Exchange%E2%84%A2+MultiCollider+SuperDropdown%E2%84%A2&nfpr=1)

Comment: Could someone please tell me whether this has anything to do with my notifications bar not showing up anymore? I used to love that bar everytime I visited this site. If not I'm going to ask a separate question for this.

Comment: @Mugen CSS issue is completely unrelated. That said, please check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66670/global-inbox-and-envelope-double-notify-me and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72840/i-dont-see-the-update-notification-bars-at-the-top-anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is in. Please verify.

[image: VERIFIED]

Comment: I've been keeping my Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ untouched in anticipation of the fix. And I can confirm.