# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ NotificationDot® is still out of position

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Google Chrome/OSX. `.unreadCount` needs `margin-top: 3px` to fix, the stylesheet specifies `0px`.

[Related question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/stack-exchange-multicollider-superdropdown-notifications-are-off-kilter-in-new)

[image: Display error]

Comment: Also happens in Safari/OSX.

Comment: i'll put a fix in soon. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.